# Default Azure Mobile App backend returning 500

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to use Azure Mobile Apps and Azure Storage to build a backend for my Xamarin.Forms app. I created everything in Azure (Mobile Service, Storage Account, ConnectionString, etc.) and downloaded the default project of the backend (as I chose C# as language) and of the Xamarin.Forms app.

Then I debugged locally the project of the backend and was working, so I published it. When I tested the Web API with the default Xamarin.Forms app, the server returned an exception (500 Internal Server Exception) with the message "An error has occured.". After that I tried to enabled server log, remote debug and xml log files, but I didn't find much.

The remote debug showed that nothing was wrong with the "visible" backend code (no exception was thrown when debugging).
The xml log files showed a Warning in an OWIN method, but no errors.
The server log showed two errors in GET requests:
[azure-log.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B33BXHpxsraGLUgzQVRnRmVfSWs)
Obs. I removed my app service name and replaced with "{servicename}".

I already tried to delete and re-create all Azure services, already tried to change from http to https and tried to change the connectionString to other values. But I did these changes only after trying to debug the default projects without any success.
I'm trying to solve this error for a while and I don't know anything more that I could do.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was happening because the default project that Azure creates for the back-end is intended to be used with SQL. As I was using Azure Storage as db, I had to modify this project.

The chapter 3 of Adrian Hall's book ([NoSQL Storage with the StorageDomainManager](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/domainmgr/#nosql-storage-with-the-storagedomainmanager)) explains exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

> Exception=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. **Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections**. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - **Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation**. **Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime** feature is enabled.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): **The system cannot find the file specified** at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection

According to the errors you provided, I assumed that you are using local database in your Azure mobile backend. You could leverage [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) or [Azure App Service Editor](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36467.understanding-the-azure-app-service-editor.aspx) to check your `MS_TableConnectionString` connectionstring under your web.config file. The connectionstring would look like this:

`<add name="MS_TableConnectionString" connectionString="Server=tcp:{your_dbservername}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog={your_dbname};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`

When deploy your mobile app to Azure via Visual Studio, you need to point your connectionstring to your Azure db as follows:

[image]

For more details about creating and deploying your mobile app to Azure App Service, you could refer to this [document](https://github.com/Microsoft/HealthClinic.biz/wiki/Create-and-deploy-a-mobile-app-in-Azure-App-Service). Also, you could leverage "All Settings > Application settings" under your web app blade to configure your connectionstring, which could override your existing connectionstring in your web.config file at runtime. For more details, you could follow this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure).

Additionally, you could follow [Adrian Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1313441/adrian-hall)'s book [here](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/) for a better understanding and a quick start with Azure Mobile Apps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried what you said but as I'm using Azure Storage, I don't have any ID or Password (required when creating a SQL db). Does Storage has a different string connection? And I'm not sure of what to put in Data Source.

Comment: I knew that when you getting your quick start project on Azure Portal, you could create a database and choose the type of Azure Storage. But as I known, azure mobile server back-end leverages SQL db to store data with your backend. You could find a connection string named `MS_TableConnectionString` in your web.config file, which uses local sql db to store your data.

Comment: Moreover, Azure Mobile Apps leverage [TableController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt587928.aspx) which could provide in-build CURD operations on tables by using EF data context, offline sync,etc.

Comment: If you don't want create the Azure sql database, you could leverage [SQL Server Compact database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-deploying-sql-server-compact-databases-2-of-12) which could be deployed with your project to Azure Mobile App.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to Back-end Logic. If I got right you think that it's not possible to create an Azure Mobile App Backend without a SQL database? I know that in previous versions (Azure Mobile Services) you could ([Build a .NET backend mobile service that uses Table storage](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/docs/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-store-data-table-storage.md)).

Comment: DOn't use those instructions - they are for Mobile Services - not Mobile Apps.  I cover using Azure Storage instead of SQL Azure in my book - http://aka.ms/zumobook - chapter 3.

Comment: Sorry for my misleading about Azure Mobile Apps. The errors you provided indicate that you are also trying to connect the sql db data store on Azure side. Have you tried to check the [tutorial](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/docs/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-store-data-table-storage.md) again for configuring the Azure Mobile Services quickstart project to use Azure Table storage? For further guide, please follow Adrian Hall's book. Or you could provide a sample project for us to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your time Bruce. I understand that my error can be misleading :). And @AdrianHall this is exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks for answering and for the time that you spent creating this awesome book! How can I close this question if a comment is the answer?

Comment: You could post a answer and provide details about what causes your issue is, and how do you solve it. In this way, it would help other community members who could encounter the same issue.